# How to add a variable to an existing model ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Very green question here.  I built a simple blog following the instructions here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

How can I add another string variable to the post object?

---

Once I have a new variable, how do I create new posts in html.erb files?  The code below gives me a NoMethodError exception for the 'email' method.  How do I make this code run without an error?

btw - what is convention on stackoverflow for followup questions?

```
<h2>Add a post:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.actions.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :number_performed %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :number %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :your_email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the very least to get the minimum functionality, you must add another column to your post table.

See here on how to add a column programitcally:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

OR you can run the rails generate migration command like so:

```
rails generate migration AddColumnNameToPost column_name:string
```

No matter what route you go down, make sure you run the following to apply those migrations to your database:

```
rake db:migrate
```

From there you can access:

```
@post = Post.new
@post.column_name = "value"
#etc
```

Answer (score 5):

same like answer from **drharris**:

```
rails generate migration add_newvariableone_and_newvariabletwo_to_modelpluralname newvariableone:string newvariabletwo:string
```

it will create ruby file inside db/migrate where the content like

```
class AddNewVariableOneAndNewVariableTwoToModelPluralname < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :modelpluralname, :newvariableone, :string
    add_column :modelpluralname, :newvariabletwo, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :modelpluralname, :newvariableone
    remove_column :modelpluralname, :newvariableone
  end
end
```

hope this help you thanks

Comment: This answer is more helpful I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the section on [Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). In your case, you would use a command like:

```
rails generate migration AddRandomStringToPost random_string:string
```